# How can I set in vscode a default java configuration in launch.json to make vscode stop asking me to specify a main class every time I run the app?

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code

every time I start my Java application, vscode asks me to specify the main Class for my java configuration, even though I already did it in launch.json.
bit i believe what it's asking me is to choose a certain configuration to run from.
so my question is:

***is there a way to make a default Configuration to run from in launch.json?***

this is my launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "admin-ui",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "mainClass": "com.bla.blo.Application",
        "projectName": "admin-ui",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class is kind of `public` and includes the function `public static void main(String[] args)`, java extension will recognize it as **mainClass** and auto-complete it in launch.json.

About you saying:

> vscode asks me to specify the main Class for my java configuration

It's may because when your debugging option is **Current File** ,you have more than one mainclass, so java extension will ask you to select one to run:

[image]

Anyway, the solution is selecting the option which `name` is in `mainClass`
configuration from the debug drop-down box on the left. From the configuration in your launch.json, you should choose **admin-ui**.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can set the default launch configuration, then after that, you can use `F5` to launch the default one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm using this from now on!